# MySql subquery inside View

Tags: mysql, subquery

I created a view using MySql subquery, it worked on my localhost,
it failed in production because Mysql version is 5.6, it doesn't support subqueries on views, so i need help rewriting the whole query,
I tried with UNION ALL but it tells me i need the same amount of columns for each Select.

New query:

```
CREATE VIEW vista_inventarionacional AS
  SELECT T.Ultima_Actualizacion,
   r.nombre AS Red,
   co.nombre AS Comuna,
   equipo.nombre AS Descripcion,
   equipo.marca AS Marca,
   equipo.modelo AS Modelo,
   p.nombre AS Parametro,
   equipo.nserie AS NumSerie,
   equipo.fecha_compra AS Fecha_Recepcion,
   equipo.id_mma AS MMA,
   equipo.fecha_inicio_uso AS FechaInstalacion,
   equipo.fecha_vigencia as FechaBaja,
   e.nombre AS LugarInstalacion,
   eq_etd.nombre AS EstadoEquipo
   FROM equipo
   LEFT JOIN equipo_estacion AS eq_est ON eq_est.equipo_id = equipo.id
   JOIN estacion AS e ON e.id = eq_est.estacion_id
   LEFT JOIN red AS r ON r.id = e.red_id
   LEFT JOIN comuna AS co ON co.id = e.comuna_id
   LEFT JOIN equipo_parametro AS eq_p ON eq_p.equipo_id = equipo.id
   JOIN parametro AS p ON p.id = eq_p.parametro_id
   LEFT JOIN equipo_estado AS eq_etd ON eq_etd.id = equipo.equipo_estado_id
   WHERE eq_est.estado = 'activo';
   UNION ALL
   SELECT equipo_id, MAX(fecha) AS Ultima_Actualizacion
   FROM transferencia GROUP BY equipo_id
```

Old Query with Subquery:
[image: Original]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
UNION ALL
   SELECT equipo_id, MAX(fecha) AS Ultima_Actualizacion
   FROM transferencia GROUP BY equipo_id
```

is incorrect. Because in 1st query you have 14 column you try to union all with 2 column.

You can use :

```
SELECT equipo_id, MAX(fecha), null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null, AS Ultima_Actualizacion
   FROM transferencia GROUP BY equipo_id;
```

Also View's select contains a subquery error: You can solve this. Use mysql workbrench to connect mysql DB. and run create view script from mysqlworkbrench.
It will work.